# how to display files uploaded in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

im building an HR system with laravel , i can add many employees , and for every employee i can upload many documents , the problem is i can fetch just 1 file for every employee and i cannot fetch more than 1 [1 file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxAcy.png)

this is espacedocController.php :

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use App\User;
    use App\Espacedocs;

    class EspacedocsController extends Controller {

   public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    $request->validate([
        'doc' => 'required',
    ]);

    $employee = User::findOrFail($id);
    $doc = new Espacedocs();

    if ($request->hasFile('doc')) {

        $file = $request->file('doc');
        $extention = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = time() . '.' . $extention;
        $file->move('uploads/docs/', $filename);

        $fileOriginalName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    }
    $doc->user_id = $id;
    $doc->doc_url = $filename;
    $doc->nom_doc = $fileOriginalName;
    $doc->save();

   
   return redirect()->back();
   }

    public function getFile($filename) {
    $file = Storage::disk('public/uploads/docs')->get($filename);

    return (new Response($file, 200));
   }

   }
```

this is my employeeController.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use App\User;
use App\Role;
use App\Schedule;
use App\Http\Requests\EmployeeRec;

class EmployeeController extends Controller {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function index() {
    
    return view('admin.employee')->with(['employees' => User::all(), 'schedules' =>
```

Schedule::all()]);
}

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(EmployeeRec $request) {
    $employee = new User;
    $employee->firstname = $request->firstname;
    $employee->lastname = $request->lastname;
    $employee->dateofbirth = $request->dateofbirth;
    $employee->nationality = $request->nationality;
    $employee->department = $request->department;
    $employee->position = $request->position;
    $employee->salary = $request->salary;
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $extention = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = time() . '.' . $extention;
        $file->move('uploads/employees/image/', $filename);
        $employee->image = $filename;
    }
    $employee->name = $request->name;
    $employee->email = $request->email;
    $employee->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $employee->pin_code = $request->pin_code;
    $employee->save();

    if ($request->schedule) {

        $schedule = Schedule::whereSlug($request->schedule)->first();

        $employee->schedules()->attach($schedule);
    }
    
    $role = Role::whereSlug('emp')->first();

    $employee->roles()->attach($role);

    return redirect()->route('employees.index')->with('success', 'Employee Has Been Created Successfully');
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param   \App\User  $employee
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(EmployeeRec $request, User $employee) {
 
    $employee->firstname = $request->firstname;
    $employee->lastname = $request->lastname;
    $employee->dateofbirth = $request->dateofbirth;
    $employee->nationality = $request->nationality;
    $employee->department = $request->department;
    $employee->position = $request->position;
    $employee->salary = $request->salary;
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        
        $destination = 'uploads/employees/image'.$employee->image;
        if(File::exists($destination))
        {
            File::delete($destination);
        }
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $extention = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = time() . '.' . $extention;
        $file->move('uploads/employees/image/', $filename);
        $employee->image = $filename;
    }
    $employee->name = $request->name;
    $employee->email = $request->email;
    
    $employee->pin_code =$request->pin_code;
    $employee->save();

    if ($request->schedule) {

        $schedule = Schedule::whereSlug($request->schedule)->first();

        $employee->schedules()->attach($schedule);
    }
  $employee->update();

    return redirect()->route('employees.index')->with('success', 'Employee Has Been Updated Successfully');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param   \App\User  $employee
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy(User $employee) {
    $employee->delete();
    return redirect()->route('employees.index')->with('success', 'Employee Has Been Deleted Successfully');
}

public function show($id) {
 
    $user=User::findOrFail($id);
    $employee = $user->employees->first();
 return view('admin.employee')->with(['employee' => $employee , 'user' => $user]);

}

}
```

and this is the view where i can fetch the file :

```
   <!-- Edit -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="show{{$employee->id}}" class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Profile Details</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">X</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>

        </div>
        <div class="main-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="well">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center text-center">

                                    <img src="{{ asset('uploads/employees/image/'.$employee->image) }}" class="rounded-circle " width="110" height="110">
                                    <div class="mt-3">
                                        <h4 style="color:MediumSeaGreen;">{{$employee->firstname}} {{$employee->lastname}}</h4>
                                        <p style="color:MediumSeaGreen;"class="text-secondary mb-1">{{$employee->position}}</p>
                                        <p style="color:orange;"class="text-muted font-size-sm">{{$employee->nationality}}</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-5 well">
                    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Full Name</th>
                                <td>{{$employee->firstname}} {{$employee->lastname}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Email</th>
                                <td>{{$employee->email}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Date of Birth</th>
                                <td>{{$employee->dateofbirth}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Phone</th>
                                <td>{{$employee->phone}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Nationality</th>
                                <td>{{$employee->nationality}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Salary</th>
                                <td>{{$employee->salary}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3">Documents</h5>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <div class="card card-user">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>  Click to download the documents</label><br>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">

                                            @if(isset($employee->espacedocs->first()->doc_url))
                                            <a href="{{asset('uploads/docs/'.$employee->espacedocs->first()->doc_url)}}"><i class="icon-download-alt"> </i> {{$employee->espacedocs->first()->nom_doc}} </a>
                                            @endif

                                        </div>
                                        <hr>
                                        <form action="{{ route('EspaceDocs.update', $employee->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
                                            {{csrf_field()}}
                                            {{method_field('PUT')}}
                                            <label>  Insert New document</label>
                                            <input type="file" name="doc" class="form-control">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Add</button>
                                        </form>
                                        <br>
                                        <br>
                                        <br>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and this is all the files uploded in the project :
[docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IE9P.png)

hope you guys can help me to fetch all files !

Answer (score 0):

In your case I think you want to upload employees image and docs in laravel public directory so you can use the `asset()` function to access them in view.

In that case when you are moving the uploaded file

`$file->move('uploads/employees/image/', $filename);`

wrap the path with `public_path()` so the files will be uploaded in `public` directory like:

```
$file->move(public_path('uploads/employees/image/'), $filename);
```

so in view you can use `asset()` as normal:

```
{{ asset('uploads/employees/image/'.$employee->image) }}
```

hope this hepls

Comment: bro ! as i already say , i can upload files but the problem that i cannot fetch more than 1 , SO i think i need a boucle or something like that